# On Windows machine, installed Python 3.7 but it seem like 3.6 is running

Tags: python, python-3.x

Yesterday I uninstalled my Python 3.6 and installed Python 3.7.  I simply ran the executable and followed the prompts.  Here is a screen shot of my Programs and Features in my Control Panel.

[image]

However, when I check the version in the command prompt, it seems like version 3.6 is still running!

[image]

Comment: You probably have not completely uninstalled python3.6 and there is still the remaining binary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a Python executable in your PATH from a [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) installation (hence the `Anaconda Inc` at the end of your version number).

You have a few options here:

1. You can either find the Anaconda installation and remove it (`echo %path%` into the command prompt may help).
2. [Edit your PATH](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/) to make sure that your Python 3.7.3 installation is called first before the Anaconda install.
3. [Upgrade your Anaconda installation](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section) to the latest version that uses Python 3.7.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an Anaconda Python installation, you can either upgrade it to your chosen version of Python or create a new `conda` environment with the version you want.

To see what environments you have set up, do `conda env list`

To upgrade Python in an environment `myenv`, do `activate myenv` then `conda update python` (to get the latest version) or `conda install python=x.y.z` (to install version x.y.z, assuming it's available from your `conda` channels)

Answer (score 2):

You probably didn't completely uninstall your old python version and windows is still pointing to the old installation. Edit your PATH and point your new python 3.7 directory.

Go to My Computer/This PC --> right click --> properties --> advanced system settings --> environment variables --> PATH

You should see a path directory that looks something like this:

> C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python36\

Change that directory and point to your python 3.7 installation.

If you want you can keep the old installation of python 3.6 on your computer, it's not necessary to uninstall it and you can work on projects using older python versions when needed.

Comment: Thanks for all the help with all of this, everyone.  Really appreciate it.  In the end, it wasn't any one things that resolved the problem, but rather it was a combination of a bunch of suggestions listed above.  Some of my own judgement and common sense was applied as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you install anaconda, a box is automatically checked to make your computer see the version of python installed with conda as the primary version, you could probably uninstall conda or change you system env path taking conda off it.